# Sorting database on changes

Tags: entity-framework

Is there way to keep database sorted? My goal is to keep it sorted so I won't have to call `orderBy` each time user requests data.

I tried following:

```
_context.Users.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedAt);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: A database doesn't have an implicit order and doesn't guarantee that retrieval order matches insertion order. Why don't you want to `OrderBy()` on each call?

Comment: I just consider it more efficient, because there will be more requests than changes.

Comment: And if you could help me with one more question, lets say that I have like a few thousands users in my DB, and also a page responsible for showing them. Of course showing them all is not possible, so lets say it will be 50 per page, is it ok to use Skip and Take methods? or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there way to keep database sorted?

In most relational databases Indexes are implemented as BTrees, which support both efficient retrieval of single rows, *and* ordered retrieval of multiple rows.

So just make sure your database has the right indexes for efficient ordered retrieval.  You can even [create indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) from EF in Code First.